# Getting MongoDB collection after change in page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

Right now I am working with Jade, NodeJS, and MongoDB with Monk to create a website.

What I want to happen is that there is an update in the page(in this case the user moves the google maps), and then the collection is fetched again from the database using new parameters (the updated latitude and longitude), and then that collection is used to update the items on the page (the search shows the items in the new latitude longitude area)

Here's the nodejs code for the get, that currently just shows everything in the database

```
router.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('items')
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
       res.render('searchAll', {
          "itemlist" : docs
       });
    });
});
```

and the jade code

```
each item, i in itemlist
   #{item.stuff}
```

and some javascript code that activates when the user moves the map (and grabs the new latitude and longitude) that I won't show because it works.

so how do I recall the database with the new latitude and longitude and re run that jade code, to display the updated itemList?

**EDIT**

I can now get the data from the database, and display it on the page, but how do I get jade (or js?) to reiterate over the new data and display it on the page?

```
button(onclick="httpGet('/afibo5')")
  | Click
p#response

script(type='text/javascript').
  function httpGet(theUrl){
    //document.write(theUrl);
    $.get(
      theUrl, 
      { id: "532169"}, 
      function(responseText){
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=responseText;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: googling everything, I have no idea how to tackle this, I am generally a backend developer, and don't have much experience with javascript. I basically want to be able to push a button, that button queries the database and displays the results on the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to click event to do: window.location.href='/search?lat=5&lon=10';

Comment: but I want it to be seamless, without redirect or refresh of page

Comment: Use jquery.ajax and send get request to /api/search (add additional route from my code example)

Comment: that worked, i moved my jade loop to a new .jade, got the res to render that page, and then updated the id=response to the responsetext

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
router.get('/search', function(req, res) { 
    req.query = _.pick(req.query, ['lat', 'lon']); // filter query param for exact parameters, if they will not exist it will be empty object
    // query mongo for documents with given lat, lon
    req.db.get('items').find(req.query,{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('searchAll', { "itemlist" : docs }); 
    });
});

// for ajax calls, responds with json, that have to be iterated and rendered using frontend code
router.get('/api/search', function(req, res) { 
    req.query = _.pick(req.query, ['lat', 'lon']);
    req.db.get('items').find(req.query,{},function(e,docs){
        res.json({ "itemlist" : docs }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: ok I can now get the data from the database, and display it on the page, but how do I get jade to reiterate over the new data?

Comment: res.render does it, it gets view file and renders with new data. But if You're requesting wih Ajax, so tell me I'll change code.

Comment: Oh I see, but how do I get javascript to reload the page? right now if I click the button it makes it so there are two versions of the page. Or just a specific part of the page (ie: only the body needs to be changed)

Comment: Bind to click event to do: window.location.href='/search?lat=5&lon=10';